# Using cat for a progress bar

Tags: r, progress-bar, cat

I'm trying to make a simple in-console progress bar so that I can see how far along my code is. I know there exist built-in options like txtProgressBar and winProgressBar but I was hoping to be able to format one myself. I'd like it to update in the same line rather than outputting a series of lines.

I currently have something that I feel should work - and sometimes does work fine - but also sometimes glitches out in ways I don't understand. This is my code:

```
for(i in 1:10000){
  #Rest of my code
  cat('\r',paste("Working  [",strrep("#",i/n*50),strrep(" ",50-i/n*50),"]   ",ceiling(i/n*100),"%",sep=""))
}
```

As far as I can tell this should format correctly every time. However by the time the program finishes the output usually looks something like this:

```
Working  [##################################################]   100%rking  [                                                 ]   5%
```

I can't figure out what goes wrong. Neither flush.console() nor Sys.sleep seems to help. Any advice or ideas would be appreciated. In case it matters, I'm using RStudio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me both in the R console and in RStudio under Windows

```
n = 1000
cat("Working: ")
for(i in 1:n) {
    signal = floor(n/200)
    if(!(i %% signal)) { 
        prog = floor(i/n*50)
        cat('\r', "Working  [", strrep("#",prog), 
            strrep(" ", 50-prog), "] ", 2*prog, "%", sep="")
        flush.console() 
      }
    ## Pretend that some work is being done. 
    Sys.sleep(0.001)
    if(i == n) { cat(" \n\r") }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So the idea is to update the progress much more infrequently - smart. Since there are only 50 characters I think you could have used n/50 instead of n/200, and I'm going to use n/100 so I can have a percentage tracker. I still run into the original output issue with your implementation when I set n=200 (since this condition triggers every cycle), and I'm not sure what causes it, but I made signal a minimum of 10 and that seems to work fine.

Final question: I don't notice any difference at all using flush.console() under any parameters. Can you explain the reason for it?

Comment: I see that it works _without_ the `flush.console` in RStudio. However,  in the RGui,  if you do not include that, you see no display until the end and the all of the printout comes at the same time. Not useful.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a wheel. No need to re-invent:

```
library(dplyr)

n <- 10000
pb <- progress_estimated(n)
for(i in 1:n){
  pb$tick()$print()
  # your code goes here
}
```

Comment: OP mentioned two other wheels, but was specifically asking about reinvention,

Comment: Aye, but for something like this it's kinda important to suggest focusing on getting real work done vs code up something that's been solved multiple times. This may prevent someone else new to R from trying to waste their time as well. I care not about ticks to the answer buttons.

Comment: I appreciate your functional perspective and think it's often very helpful. That said, there are a few reasons I wanted my own implementation. I'm often required to use fresh installs of R, and the fewer libraries I need to install the better (the one you suggest requires installing 7). There's also custom information I wanted to put in the progress bar that I wouldn't be able to implement with built-in packages. And most of all I was interested in what was actually going wrong under the hood, though unfortunately I still don't actually understand what it was.

Comment: This answer was exactly what I was looking for. Nice light implementation in a package I'm already using to give a progress status and time estimate within a single line of output. I'm downloading a bunch of files from a list of URLs and wanted to display progress. This fit the bill perfectly and requires no additional customization on my end. Once again, `dplyr` to the rescue. Thanks for posting.